# Cordova Socket Programming

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I have two cordova apps, which needs to be connected via socket. Is it possible to do this only via javascipt.

ie; Without a backend infrastructure.A peer to peer communication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this plugin to create a socket server inside the phone:**
Plugin: https://github.com/becvert/cordova-plugin-websocket-server

Plugin: https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-socket

    Doc: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket

---

**And for client connection use:**

Plugin: https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp

    Doc: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp

Plugin: https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp

    Doc: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp

Use required plugin.

Thanks.